# A way to group digits using scripting

Tags: python, algorithm, shell, awk

I have a large (800K - unique and sorted) list of numbers. For example

```
    1002230091         => 1002230091 <- not a complete set of digits
    ...
    1112223000   --
    1112223001     |
    1112223002     |  
    ...            |   => 111223
    1112223009     |
    ...            |
    1112223999     |
    ...            |
    1112223999   --
    ...
```

The digits above can be grouped for the common prefix:

```
 111222300[0..9] <-- a.k.a called complete set of digits
```

Note the prefix itself can have a complete set of digits, therefore if so it should be grouped up as well.

Expected result (assuming after analysis it was found that all complete sets of digits were found for):

```
1112223
10022330091
```

I have attempted to create a script using Tree::Trie (for faster lookup) and plain old hash (to iterate through keys).

The logic I have put together doesn't get to the root prefix, it only performs one round of grouping:

```
1000  --
1001    |
1002    | => 100
...     |
1009  --
1010      => 1010
```

Additionally, it is very slow to iterate through this amount of data.

I am certain there are ** better alternative**, both from sake of speed to process this data as well as meeting this need.

Your advice/assistance in addressing this need, is much appreciated. I am most familiar with Shell or Perl scripting, however, open to any type of scripting solution.

Here is the logic I have put together, it does one round of grouping, however, doesn't perform the second round of grouping.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use Tree::Trie;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;
use Pod::Usage;

my %w_mk;
my $csv = "./test.csv";
my $debug = 1;
my($trie) = new Tree::Trie;
my $help = 0;
my $man  = 0;
my $cycle = 1;
my $max_key_length = 1;
my $min_key_length = 1;

GetOptions("debug=i"             => \$debug,
           "source_file|s=s"     => \$csv,
           "cycle|c=i"           => \$cycle,
           "help|?"              => \$help,
           "man!"                => \$man
           ) or pod2usage("Try '$0 --help' for more information." );

pod2usage(-verbose => 99, -section => "NAME") if $help;
pod2usage(-verbose => 2) if $man;

sub clean_ds
{
  my ($key, @keys) = @_;
  my $key_len = scalar @keys;

  if ($key_len == 10) {
    foreach my $k (@keys) {
      $trie->remove($k);
    }

    print "\t\tRoot key $key found!!\n" if ($debug > 1);

    ## Add this working key as a new key
    $w_mk{$key} = 2;

    ## remove all of the related complete keys
    delete @w_mk{@keys};

    print "\t\tRemoved keys: [@keys]\n\n" if ($debug > 1);
  }
}

sub is_complete_key
{
  my ($key) = @_;
  my $len = length $key;
  my (@key_list) = $trie->lookup($key, $len + 1);
  my ($key_list_len) = scalar @key_list;

  ## When a key has been processed once,
  ## let's mark it that it has been processed
  $w_mk{$key} = 2;

  print "\t\tSearch for key: '$key'\n\t\tNo. of items found: $key_list_len\n\t\titems : [@key_list]\n" if ($debug >= 3);

  # Complete DNIS found
  if ($key_list_len == 10) {
    #because trie lookup when prefix length is supplied returns only the suffix portion
    #e.g. 1000, 1001, 1002, 1003
    #when lookup('100', 4) returns 0, 1, 2, 3
    #update the returned key list by prepending it with the original key

    my @t_key_list =  @key_list;
    for my $elem (@t_key_list) {
      $elem = $key.$elem;
    }

    clean_ds($key, @t_key_list);

    return (1, @t_key_list);
  }
  else {
    print "\t\tRoot key $key not adding!!\n\n" if ($debug > 1);
  }

  return (0, @key_list);
}

open (my $handle, '<', $csv) or die "Could not open file '$csv' $!";;

while (my $row = <$handle>) {
  chomp($row);

  my $k_len = length($row);
  $max_key_length = $k_len if ($k_len > $max_key_length);

  $trie->add($row);
  $w_mk{$row} = 1;

  print "data: '$row'\n" if ($debug >= 4);
}

close ($handle);

sub group_keys
{
  my ($key, $iteration) = @_;

  my $value = 0;
  if (exists $w_mk{$key}) {
    $value = $w_mk{$key};
    chomp($value);
  }

  while ($value >= $iteration && length $key > 1) {
    chop($key); # Remove last character of the key

    if (exists $w_mk{$key}) {
      $value = $w_mk{$key};
      chomp($value);
    }

    print "\t(w_key => w_value): '$key' => '$value'\n" if ($debug >= 2);

    ## If the working key has already been processed once,
    ## no need to reprocess it
    if ($value < 2) {
      my ($st, @w_key_list) = is_complete_key($key);

      ##
      ## if number of keys found is less than 10
      ## no need to continue to chop the key
      ## go to the next key
      ##
      #if ($st == 0) {
        last;
      #}
    }
  }
}

sub go_through_keys
{
  my ($lcycle) = @_;

  print "Reduction Cycle: '$lcycle'\n\n" if ($debug >= 3);

  foreach my $key (sort keys %w_mk) {
    my $w_key = $key;
    my $w_value = 0;

    if (exists $w_mk{$w_key}) {
      $w_value = $w_mk{$w_key};
      chomp($w_value);
    }

    print "(Key => Value): '$key' => '$w_value'\n" if ($debug >= 2);
    if ($debug >= 3) {
      my (@keys) = $trie->lookup($key);
      my $key_len = scalar @keys;
      print "\t\tNo. of items found: $key_len\n\t\titems : [@keys]\n" if ($debug >= 3);
    }

    group_keys($w_key, $lcycle);
  }
}

sub reset_key_values
{
  foreach my $key (keys %w_mk) {
    $w_mk{$key} = 1;
  }
}

for (my $i=$min_key_length; $i < $max_key_length; $i++) {
  go_through_keys($i);
  # reset values for each key
  #reset_key_values();
}
print "$_\n" for sort keys %w_mk;

__END__

=head1 NAME

  group_dnis.pl - A script to group and reduce a list of numbers

=head1 SYNOPSIS

  group_dnis.pl - A script to group and reduce a list of numbers

              ------------------------------
                 dnis(s)  => common root
              ------------------------------
                 1000   --
                 1001    |
                 1002    | ==> 100
                 1003    |
                 ...     |
                 1009   --
                 1010      ==> 1010


group_dnis.pl [options]
  Options:
    -help     brief help message
    -man      full documentation

=head1 OPTIONS

=over 4

=item B<-source_file>

  Source file contain list of numbers to be groupped.

=item B<-help>

  Prints usage with some examples of how to use this script.

  group_dnis.pl -s <file name>

=back

  Documentation ends here.

=cut
```

Comment: After you've determined the "complete" prefixes, how do you know (and is it important at all?) how many extra digits it had? You've given two examples, `10[00...10]` and `1112223[000...999]`, but how do we know if `1112223` was not `1112223[0...9]` before and maybe `10` was actually `10[00000...99999]`? Do all the numbers have the same number of digits?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For my need, it doesn't matter how many extra digits were there, I am more interested in the root prefix.

For second part of your comment, all numbers have same number of digits.

Comment: So `10[00...10]` would not exist in your data, right? It would have to be `10[00000000...99999999]` to be considered complete?

Comment: `Data   Group 1 Group 2
1000 100 10
1001 100 10
1002 100 10
1003 100 10
1004 100 10
1005 100 10
1006 100 10
1007 100 10
1008 100 10
1009 100 10
1010 101 10
1011 101 10
1012 101 10
1013 101 10
1014 101 10
1015 101 10
1016 101 10
1017 101 10
1018 101 10
1019 101 10
1020 102 10
1021 102 10
1022 102 10
1023 102 10
1024 102 10
1025 102 10
1026 102 10
1027 102 10
1028 102 10
1029 102 10
1030 103 10
...
1091 109 10
1092 109 10
1093 109 10
1094 109 10
1095 109 10
1096 109 10
1097 109 10
1098 109 10
1099 109 10`

Comment: I thought you said all numbers are the same length, no? What is that length? Please define exactly what you mean by "complete." Would `10[0..8]` be considered complete? Would `10[0..10]` be considered complete? If not, would you then list `10[0..8]` individually?

Comment: Also, how would you process `10[0..17]`? Would you list them all individually, or would you return `10` (grouping `10[0..9]`) and then list `10[10..17]` individually?

Comment: All numbers are of same length. The definition of **complete** is if all numbers 10[0..9] exist. For example, if all numbers from 1000...1009 exist, this set of number can be grouped as 100. If complete list doesn't exist, then yes, will like to list them individually.

Comment: For numbers 10[0..17], i.e. 100, 101, ... 117, the final list would be 10, 111, 112, ... 117. Total numbers in the final list will be 8.

Comment: That does not seem consistent. If you say `10[0..9] ` should return `100` then `10[0..17]` should return `100, 110, 111, 112...117` no?

Comment: Oops, I wasn't clear - I meant `10[00..17]`, which I think should return `100,1010,1011,1012..1017`

Answer (score 0):

Here's something linear in JavaScript (assumes `list` is sorted). Converting to AWK shouldn't be too bad. Not sure if it's full-proof...might want to debug against the real data.

```js
function f(list){         
  var i = 0, j = 9, k = 0, tempList = [list[i]];
  function group(){
    while (list[i + 1] && list[i].substr(0,j) == list[i + 1].substr(0,j) 
        && Number(list[i].substr(j - 10)) + 1 == list[i + 1].substr(j - 10)){
      tempList.push(list[i + 1]);
      i++;
    }
  }
  function isComplete(){
    return Number(tempList[0].substr(j-10)) + Math.pow(10,10 - j) - 1 
        == tempList[tempList.length - 1].substr(j-10);
  }
  while (i < list.length - 2){
    group();
    if (isComplete()){
      if (list[i + 1] && list[i].substr(0,j - 1) == list[i + 1].substr(0,j - 1) 
        && Number(list[i].substr(j - 1 - 10)) + 1 == list[i + 1].substr(j - 1 - 10)){
        j--;
        k++;
      } else {
        console.log(tempList[0].substr(0,j)); // output
        tempList = [list[++i]];
        j = 9; k = 0;
      }
    } else {
      console.log(tempList[0].substr(0,j + 1)) // output
      for (l=Math.pow(10,k); l<tempList.length; l++)
      console.log(tempList[l]); // output
      tempList = [list[++i]];
      j = 9; k = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
console.log(f(['1002230091','1112223000','1112223001','1112223002','1112223003'
              ,'1112223004','1112223005','1112223006','1112223007','1112223008'
              ,'1112223009']));
/*
  1002230091
  111222300
*/

console.log(f(['1002230091','1112223000','1112223001','1112223002','1112223003'
              ,'1112223004','1112223005','1112223006','1112223007','1112223008'
              ,'1112223009','1112223010','1112223011','1112223012']));

/*
1002230091
111222300
1112223010
1112223011
1112223012
*/
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your comments. I will push it through the data I have and revert back to you.